# Google Spreadsheets: How do you concat strings in an aggregation function

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have a table:

```
A, 1
B, 1
C, 2
D, 1
E, 2
```

How do I view the table grouping by the 2nd column and aggregating by the first with a comma separated concat function ie:

```
1, "A,B,D"
2, "C,E"
```

In both defining a pivot table and using the QUERY syntax, it seems that the only aggregation functions available are numerical aggregations like MIN, MAX, SUM, etc. Can I define my own aggregation function?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a pivot table will do that for you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to add a "Calculated Field" to the pivot table, and then select "Summarise by > Custom". This will make the column names in your formula refer to an *array* of values (instead of a single value). Then you can type a formula like:

`= JOIN(", ", MyStringColumn)`

More specifically, if you have the following table:

[image: Original table]

Create a pivot table by going to "Data > Pivot table", with the following configuration. Ensure "Summarize by" is set to "Custom"!

[image: Pivot table]

Comment: MyStringColumn - Is that something like "F2:F" or something else?

Comment: No, it's the column header of your original data

Comment: Note that the column name must be a valid identifier. I used "name-email" as a column header. The naive use in the join was `=join(", ", name-email)`, which was interpreted as name minus email. Changing the column header and the join to underscores worked.

Comment: @Reece If you want to use column names like that, you can also wrap the name in single quotes in the formula (e.g. `=join(", ", 'name-email')`)

Comment: BTW, if you need to only do unique items, you can do a double pivot. First pivot has Letters and Numbers as rows (with "repeat row labels" for the first row item), and then you can use this join as calculated value on second pivot.

Comment: Is it possible to give a calculated field a name so it doesn't just show as “Calculated Field”? I have multiple columns fields, so the “Calculated Field” header appears multiple times and I'd like to not have to change them all manually. (For that matter, is it possible to rename anything in a pivot table? “AVERAGE of My Column Name” is kind of verbose.)

Answer (score 8):

Another option: if the data is in A2:B, then, say, in D2:

`=UNIQUE(B2:B)`

and then in E2:

`=JOIN(",",FILTER(A$2:A,B$2:B=D2))`

which is filled down as required.

There are one-formula, auto-expanding solutions, although they get quite convoluted.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, there's no easy way with pivot tables. This though, will do the trick. Inspired by this brilliant answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/453252).

First, have a header row and run a sort on column A to group by category.

So far, in your example, we have

```
   |     A     |     B
---+-----------+-----------
 1 |  CATEGORY | ATTRIBUTE
 2 |     1     |     A
 3 |     1     |     B
 4 |     1     |     D
 5 |     2     |     C
 6 |     2     |     E
```

In column C, let's prep the concatenated strings. Start in cell C2 with the following formula, and fill out vertically.

```
=IF(A2<>A1, B2, C1 & "," & B2)
```

...looking good...

```
   |     A     |     B     |     C
---+-----------+-----------+-----------
 1 |  CATEGORY | ATTRIBUTE |  STRINGS
 2 |     1     |     A     |     A
 3 |     1     |     B     |    A,B
 4 |     1     |     D     |   A,B,D
 5 |     2     |     C     |     C
 6 |     2     |     E     |    C,E
```

In column D, let's validate the rows we want to select in a later step, with the following formula, starting in cell D2 and filling out. Basically we are marking the final category rows that carry the full concatenated strings.

```
=A2<>A3
```

...almost there now

```
   |     A     |     B     |     C    |     D
---+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------
 1 |  CATEGORY | ATTRIBUTE |  STRINGS | VALIDATOR
 2 |     1     |     A     |     A    |   FALSE
 3 |     1     |     B     |    A,B   |   FALSE
 4 |     1     |     D     |   A,B,D  |   TRUE
 5 |     2     |     C     |     C    |   FALSE
 6 |     2     |     E     |    C,E   |   TRUE
```

Now, lets copy column C and D and paste special as values in the same place. Then add a filter on the whole table and filter out column D for the rows labeled TRUE. Now, remove the filter, delete columns B and D and row 1.

```
   |     A     |     B       
---+-----------+-----------
 1 |     1     |    A,B,D  
 2 |     2     |     C,E
```

Done. Get ice cream. Watch [Road House](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098206/).