# A pivot table to show standings from game data

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a game data where each team plays 2 games per week.  I want to make a pivot table to get the current standings.  I would expect the below data to show Team 1 is 4-0 and Team 2 is 0-4. I've tried a lot of combinations of pivot tables but just cant quite get it. Do I need an extra column for game (1 or 2 each week)?

I've tried the following pivot table configuration:

[image: Pivot Table]

But that just leads to is saying Team 1 has 20 W's and Team 2 has 20 L's (its not just getting one unique one per game, hence why I might need game column?)

Below is sample data:

[image]

Comment: Youll need to use some formula and aggregate the W/L fields. 
Maybe change them to 0/1 instead? I came across this link that might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974106/google-spreadsheets-how-do-you-concat-strings-in-an-aggregation-function

Comment: does it needs to be pivot table? how about some simple query formula?

Comment: I can see a complication as well, that you'd have to find a way of establishing that both teams have played two matches in the same week (because week number, team and score are all identical in the sample data). Can you assume that there are always five players?