# Group everything by Column A and have Column B be a comma-delimited list of values

Tags: split, google-sheets-formula, trim, flatten, google-query-language

I've got a Google Sheets worksheet with data like this:

| Product | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | Cyan |
| Product B | Cyan |
| Product C | Cyan |
| Product A | Magenta |
| Product C | Magenta |
| Product B | Yellow |
| Product C | Yellow |
| Product A | Black |
| Product B | Black |

What I'd like to do group everything by Column A and have Column B be a comma-delimited list of values that share Column A in common, like so:

| Product | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | Cyan,Magenta,Black |
| Product B | Cyan,Yellow,Black |
| Product C | Cyan,Magenta,Yellow,Black |

Query ?  Arrayformula ?  Both ?

Comment: Alternative with pivot table: [Google Spreadsheets: How do you concat strings in an aggregation function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436264/16125139)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY({ROW(A1:A), A1:A&"×", B1:B&","}, 
 "select max(Col3) where not Col2 starts with '×' 
  group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×")), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
={UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, B:B<>"")), BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, B:B<>"")), 
 LAMBDA(aa, JOIN(", ", FILTER(B:B, A:A=aa))))}
```

[image]