# Is there a way to use arrayformula in google sheet to join text with conditions?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements

Is there a way to get the result column in the picture below?
All i want to do is text join the Col1 if the corresponding Col2 belongs to the same groups (E.G. 1,2,3....).
Reminded that I want to use arrayformula instead of dragging down the "normal" formula myself everytime.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73715135/5632629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this formula**
Or [***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p0e3tTMWwFLrU8fNtI9vXUSvcuZGtQpv3ajCs2zz4Bg/copy) of this example sheet.

```
=ArrayFormula({"Result";
                IF(A2:A="",,
                BYROW(B2:B,
                LAMBDA(v,JOIN(", ",FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=v)))))})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Great news for google-sheet lovers that google releases new lambda formulas. You can use `BYROW()` function to make it spill array. Try below formula.

```
=BYROW(C3:C9,LAMBDA(x,JOIN(",",FILTER(B3:B9,C3:C9=x))))
```

To refer entire column use `FILTER()` function for `BYROW()`.

```
=BYROW(FILTER(C3:C,C3:C<>""),LAMBDA(x,JOIN(",",FILTER(B3:B,C3:C=x))))
```

[image]

Comment: Yey new formulas 

Comment: Would you please share your google sheet. I am new to the formula "Lambda" and "BYROW". I copy and paste your formula there and cannot make it work :(

Comment: @helloworld Please share a google-sheet and I will put formula to your sheet.

Comment: I've looked it up into the internet. Is the function "Lambda" limited to some users only? I've checked this new https://www.techrepublic.com/article/google-sheets-gains-lamba-functions/. It said "These new features began to be available in Google Sheets for most people on Aug. 24, 2022. Frontline, Nonprofits and legacy G Suite Basic and Business customers will not gain these features. "

Comment: Anyway, I share my sheet to you. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SiUf5ygJno9LjyXbwug_XmLhv3O2Va3pbYGLVeKsNfg/edit?usp=sharing

Many thanks to your quick reply!

Comment: Oh. somehow I refresh the page and your formula works, Thanks man. You saved me alot of time!

Comment: @helloworld See your sheet.

Comment: [Update] I found out my lambda function only works after the browser refresh. Any Idea ?
You can see what happen after i make changes to col 1 on the sheet

Answer (score -1):

Suppose my range of data from B3:C9, want to group the result according the the Column C (or Col2)
Here is the formula i googled without using the Lambda function

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(  QUERY(QUERY({ROW(C3:C9), C3:C9&"×", B3:B9&","},   "select max(Col3) where not Col2 starts with '×'    group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,7^7)), "×")), ",$", ))
```

Notice the 7^7 is the (length of the data)^(length of the data).
i.e. from 3 to 9, there are 7 data.